# How to set Overflow:hidden but still make scrollbar visible?

Tags: html, css, overflow

When modal is shown I add a class with `overflow: hodden` to body tag. So content behind the modal is not scrolling. Everything is good.

BUT

If the original page is big enough to have a scrollbar, then I can see ugly shift of the page to the right, when I open the modal. I find out the reason of such behavior. `Overflow: hidden` causes scrollbar to dissapear, so that's why it is ~10px shift to the right.

My question is how to fix this. In fact, I need to apply `overflow:hidden` but still have scrollbar shown.

Comment: Could you include your HTML and CSS (if possible in a JSFiddle)?

Comment: @Roberrrt what kind of code do you need? I have my app in Meteor + React, but any code is unneccesary, my question is explained good enough. May be something like `showModal() { $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');}` and `closeModal() { $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');}` . But you really don't need that. I think you don't understand the question.

Comment: My bad, I misread your question indeed, I have provided a (possible) solution, let me know how it ends up!

Comment: I have *exactly* the same problem. Too bad there's no solution even after almost 4 years!

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
 let _scrollPosition;

 function preventScroll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.scroll(..._scrollPosition);
 }

 function lock() {
  _scrollPosition = [window.pageXOffset, window.pageYOffset];
  $(window).on('scroll touchmove', preventScroll);
 }

 function unlock() {
  $(window).off('scroll touchmove', preventScroll);
 }

 return {
  lock,
  unlock
 };
})();
```

You can just lock the scrolling position as soon as you open the modal with this code.

Comment: thank you for your asnwer! the problem is that I need user to be able to scroll the content of the modal. in your solution scrolling is disabled at all. possible use case is to get current Y-coordinate with `window.pageYOffset` and then set `position: fixed` and `top: currentY px`. But it is much easier to do that with `overflow:hidden`, that's why I want to find out about scrollbar visibility.